# How to delete duplicate records from Hive from an external partitioned table?

Tags: sql, hive

i have a hive table which is partitioned and its created as external table. I have some duplicate records in hive. So how to delete it?

Partitione key : date_created

```
Col1  Date_created  
----  ------------

A     Jan

B     Jan

A     Jan
```

I need Output as

```
Col1  Date_created  
----  ------------

A     Jan

B     Jan
```

Answer (score 1):

Using insert overwrite+distinct:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

insert overwrite table table_name partition (date_created) 
select distinct * from table_name ;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. But any idea why we give this ? set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

Comment: @DileepRDominic If we want to protect against dynamic partition insert is that the user may accidentally specify all partitions to be dynamic partitions without specifying one static partition. hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=strict to prevent the all-dynamic partition case. See here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial  And `nonstrict` means there is no restriction on dynamic partitions.

Answer (score 0):

select distinct rows and overwrite your current table like this

```
insert overwrite table tbl select distinct * from tbl;
```